# what physical android device you use for testing purpose?

Tags: android

any good recommendation of a physical android device for testing purpose?

I am looking for a device like iPod touch in Apple camp that help iOS developer to test their stuff. I know there is Nexus One, but that thing is pretty expensive and i don't really care about the phone stuff, but something that can let developers test  accelerometer, touch screen, orientation etc.

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You could try [the official Android unlocked dev phones](http://android.brightstarcorp.com/index.htm)

But really, you'll want try to get a consumer-grade phone with 2.2 and 1.6, because those are the two main 'camps' I believe in terms of compatibility. Most devices that can run 2.1 will be able to run 2.2, and will eventually update, but a lot of devices running 1.6 won't ever get upgrades IMO. And 1.5 requires a lot of hacks to get things compatible with newer standards.

Here's the official historical distrubution of android versions
[image]

Comment: Many 1.6 devices will be updated to 2.1, but not to 2.2. This includes HTC Hero (very successful device) and some others.

Answer (score 1):

How much are you willing to spend? You could get a used Motorola Droid off eBay for maybe $250. If you will never, ever care about the phone features (using it as a phone), you can get a Motorola Droid with a banned ESN (i.e. Verizon will not let it on the cell network) for even less.

Otherwise, the Archos tablets/media players are in the $200-300 range. They can not access the Google Android Marketplace without some sort of hackery, if I recall.

Comment: I actually picked up my Droid for under $200 on craigslist (good esn). It's definitely a good place to keep an eye on, and for a low dpi device I've seen the Eris for as low as $100.

Comment: I was actually just looking at the Archos 32 3.2 inch device, only $141 in Amazon, very affordable (and disposable i guess). Anyone has experience with Archos as testing device? On a side topic, what is the reason Archos device cannot access the official Android Market?

Comment: Archos 32 has accelerometer, camera, but no gps and it is also resistive touchscreen(so no multi touch i guess). If i read it correctly, the main reason it cannot access official Android Market is because of the fact it does not have a phone chip inside. I feel this maybe a good choice for casual developer who just started his/her android journey....

Answer (score 1):

Android devices come with different screen sizes and resolutions so you need to test your device on a number of emulator configurations. For usability testing real device is a must though.

Tablets are not well-suited for testing cause they often have non-standard screen size and resolution. So phone is your only choice. Now you need to choose the phone that allows rooting (some phones such as Motorola Droid series make rooting harder). Finally, take a phone with the latest version which is FroYo (Android 2.2).

If you plan targeting some specific devices, then take that device of course.

Comment: The original Droid is super easy to root. The much newer Droid X and Droid 2 have been rooted, but no ability to load custom ROMs onto them, AFAIK.

Comment: All very good advice, until it got to recommending Froyo. As a **user**, you will want the latest hardware with the latest Android OS, but as a developer you will want just the opposite, otherwise you will not be able to detect many of the problems your users are going to have (just don't follow the recommendation of Macarse, 1.5 is way too low, get 1.6 at the bare minimum, may be 2.0, and only 2.2 if you plan on using that device for yourself).

Comment: @Stephen you should not recommend 2.0.x- it is deprecated. (and AFAIK no phones will have it)

Comment: @Stephan 1.6, 2.1 and 2.2 work differently. Testing on 1.6 will not expose specifics of 2.2 behavior, which did broke some things. So the best would be to target all of them. Now, if you look at statistics, 2.1 and 2.2 are already on majority of devices and will be on almost all, probably (at least, 2.1 will be). So it doesn't make sense to target 1.6 for *future* application. It was actual a year ago, but not now.

Comment: I'd go for the newer devices, like HTC Desire or Google Nexus One, Even tough they are bit more expensive, they have a good number of features. Since you can use them privately too, it's basically a good investment

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to spend money, just use the emulator. It's just fine.

If you really want to test the app, get an htc hero with 1.5. It the most incompatible phone I have ever worked with.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to choose android device for you:

A. If you haven't statistic from previous version of app.

You should buy device from potentially most popular group of devices for your future app. Currently the most popular devices with Api level 10, screen size normal and hight dpi. See developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Steps:

1. Go to http://choosedevice.com filter android devices in the way you choose (api level, ppi, screen size, resolution).
2. Choose device from the list of devices

B. If you have statistic for your app.

You should find device to cover as more android users as possible for your project.

Steps:

1. Find most popular devices for your project (for example using google analytics)
2. Group those devices by parameters on http://choosedevice.com
3. Find most popular groups
4. Find most popular devices in each group

So you should buy device from step 4, which will cover more android users than other.