# Recommendations for Android app development and test hardware

Tags: android

I’m looking for recommendations for what people are using to get access to development hardware for developing and testing Android Apps. I see three choices that make sense:

1. Buy Nexus One devices off contract from Google’s developer program (http://www.google.com/phone/detail/nexus-one)
2. Buy used or new off contract devices from Ebay or other sellers
3. Buy devices from carriers with contract and carrier discount

We have a small number of Nexus One’s we’ve purchased and some developers have their own Android phones from carriers, but I was hoping to hear ideas from others. What are you doing to get real hardware for development and testing? we have some application features that don't test well under the emulator, so we need real hardware.

I am also concerned about QA coverage. I see posts like http://blog.tweetdeck.com/android-ecosystem or the variety of devices listed at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Android_devices and I wonder do you do QA on various devices? Is there a small set of devices could give you better test coverage?

Comment: Looks like you listed all the options there.. what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Wisdom. What do people think the benefits and drawbacks are for each choice? Have people had good or bad experiences with these choices? Anyone have any great ideas to save money buying devices? Any horror stories of things gone wrong and that should be avoided? etc. Like I said, I'm looking for wisdom and trying to avoid the school of hard knocks.

Comment: Here is some wisdom I just learned. When the Nexus One was sold commercially, you could purchase one to be compatible with AT&T's US 3G frequencies. Apparently, now that the Nexus One is only available to registered Google developers, it is only available with T-Mobile US 3G frequencies. This is a subtle, but interesting point if you're buying dev hardware because you can't just pop an AT&T SIM in and get it to work on 3G.

Comment: A good thread that covers some of these points http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887753/what-physical-android-device-you-use-for-testing-purpose